# Disable click on other date (Datepicker without Jquery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Based on [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jdddpg3s/6/) I need to disable date change in condition. 
example:

```
var count = 0 ;
if (count = 0){cannot click on other date}
```

Please guide me on this, ive read other posts and i cannot use same approach.

I need to disable clicking on other date, when i was working on process related on one particular date. As an example, i was working on a form that use the current week, then suddenly i clicked on other date on mistakes, and the date will change to new date. i want to avoid thi

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe , What you want or say which date you want disable. Please elabroate in question

Comment: I need to disable clicking on other date, when i was working on process related on one particular date. As an example, i was working on a form that use the current week, then suddenly i clicked on other date on mistakes, and the date will change to new date. i want to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

Try this line inside your if condition

```
var dat=document.getElementById('#idDate');
dat.setAttribute('readonly',true);
```

Comment: Please do not use quote blocks in your posts for things that are not quotes. For ordinary paragraphs in your own voice, use ordinary paragraph text. Thanks!